# How can I edit an EditText field of MainActivity from ApplicationTest.java in Android Studio?

Tags: java, unit-testing, android-studio, android-instrumentation

I want to write a Test (instrumentation unit test) in which I want to edit an EditText field instantiated in the MainActivity in order to test the output field (TextView) instantiated in the MainActivity where there are the data my app returned to me in real time.

In other words, main problem is: how to read and modify objects instantiated in the MainActivity starting from an ApplicationTest.java file?

Answer (score 2):

Write method to Edit the edit text in main class and make this method public. In another class make Instance of MainActivity and use that method

You can make that method static also

Comment: hi panchal, thanks for your reply. I also tried this, but this error appears "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.EditText.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference"

if you want you can take a look to the code here github.com/rubik90/theweather